# How to check duplicate values in a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

Im having 5 users and 5 services.
I must catch if more than one user(s) have same service. So I created a dictionary:

```
//JMBGS represents users ids

List<string> multipleJMBGs = new List<string>();
multipleJMBGs.Add(data.jMBG);
multipleJMBGs.Add(data.secondPersonJMBG);
multipleJMBGs.Add(data.thirdPersonJMBG);
multipleJMBGs.Add(data.fourthPersonJMBG);
multipleJMBGs.Add(data.fifthPersonJMBG);
multipleJMBGs.RemoveAll(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));

//object Service has Id property, and I need to check if more than one user has the same service 
var serviceForClient = data?.Schedules[0]?.Service;
var serviceForFirstFamilyMember = data?.Schedules[1]?.Service;
var serviceForSecondFamilyMember = data?.Schedules[2]?.Service;
var serviceForThirdFamilyMember = data?.Schedules[3]?.Service;
var serviceForFourthFamilyMember = data?.Schedules[4]?.Service;

Dictionary<string, EmployeeTableDay.ServiceDTO> userService = new Dictionary<string, EmployeeTableDay.ServiceDTO>();

userService.Add(data.jMBG, serviceForClient);
userService.Add(data.secondPersonJMBG, serviceForFirstFamilyMember);
userService.Add(data.thirdPersonJMBG, serviceForSecondFamilyMember);
userService.Add(data.fourthPersonJMBG, serviceForThirdFamilyMember);
userService.Add(data.fifthPersonJMBG, serviceForFourthFamilyMember);
```

What I want to have as flag (true/false):

1. different users can have different services
2. different users can have same services
3. same users, can not have same service
4. same users can have multiple services

UPDATE #1:

```
List<string> multipleJMBGs = new List<string>();
multipleJMBGs.Add(data.jMBG);
multipleJMBGs.Add(data.secondPersonJMBG);
multipleJMBGs.Add(data.thirdPersonJMBG);
multipleJMBGs.Add(data.fourthPersonJMBG);
multipleJMBGs.Add(data.fifthPersonJMBG);
multipleJMBGs.RemoveAll(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));

var countedSchedules = data?.Schedules?.Count();

var serviceIdForClient = 0;
var serviceIdForFirstFamilyMember = 0;
var serviceIdForSecondFamilyMember = 0;
var serviceIdForThirdFamilyMember = 0;
var serviceIdForFourthFamilyMember = 0;

List<int> servicesIds = new List<int>();

if(countedSchedules >= 1 && data?.Schedules[0]?.Service != null)
{
    serviceIdForClient = data.Schedules[0].Service.Id;
    servicesIds.Add(serviceIdForClient);
}
if (countedSchedules >= 2 && data?.Schedules[1]?.Service != null)
{
    serviceIdForFirstFamilyMember = data.Schedules[1].Service.Id;
    servicesIds.Add(serviceIdForFirstFamilyMember);
}
if (countedSchedules >= 3 && data?.Schedules[2]?.Service != null)
{
    serviceIdForSecondFamilyMember = data.Schedules[2].Service.Id;
    servicesIds.Add(serviceIdForSecondFamilyMember);
}
if (countedSchedules >= 4 && data?.Schedules[3]?.Service != null)
{
    serviceIdForThirdFamilyMember = data.Schedules[3].Service.Id;
    servicesIds.Add(serviceIdForThirdFamilyMember);
}
if (countedSchedules == 5 && data?.Schedules[4]?.Service != null)
{
    serviceIdForFourthFamilyMember = data.Schedules[4].Service.Id;
    servicesIds.Add(serviceIdForFourthFamilyMember);
}

servicesIds = servicesIds.Where(x => x > 0).ToList();


//because dictionary throws an exception
for (int i = 0; i < countedSchedules; i++)
{
    multipleJMBGs[i] = i + " _ " + multipleJMBGs[i];
}

//create dictionary from two lists
var dic = multipleJMBGs.Zip(servicesIds, (k, v) => new { k, v }).ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);


var duplicateServices = dic.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                    .Select(x => new { ServiceId = x.Key, Users = x.ToList() });

var duplicateUsers = dic.GroupBy(x => x.Key.Substring(3,x.Key.Length-3)).Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                    .Select(x => new { User = x.Key, Services = x.ToList() });


if(duplicateServices > 1 && duplicateUsers.Count > 1)
{
    //show a message that it ca't be proceeed further
}
else
{
    //continue
}
```

Comment: This is a very strange data model. You have individual variables or properties for each user. This is not scalable. What happens if you have more than 5 users? Also, the services seem to be assigned to users by position (1st user <=> 1st service, 2nd user <=> 2nd service etc.), but you are removing empty users, so you will end up having missaligned services. E.g., if you remove 3rd person, then 4th person will be assigned the service that was intended for 3rd person. Is this your real data model?

Comment: There will not be more than 5 users, and you can assume that if user exists than service also exists. For example if thirdUser exists than you will have service for that index

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate values in a dictionary? Do you mean you could have different users with the same services? If so, how does that work with your current mechanism of assigning the service by order i.e. user 3 gets the 3rd service etc.? If you're checking for this is means your assignment won't always match

Comment: In order to discuss duplicate values, you must first discuss equality. What kind of equality are you after here? Reference equality? Property equality?

Answer (score 0):

Purely answering the question on how to check for duplicates within your dictionary:

You could group the values of your dictionary and look for duplicates that way.

```
var containsDuplicates = userService.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Any(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

If you want to actually see which services are used multiple times by which users, create the following grouping:

```
var duplicateServices = userService.GroupBy(x => x.Value).Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
                                   .Select(x => new { Service = x.Key, Users = x.ToList() });
```

**UPDATE #1:**

You don't necessarily have to group up both of these lists if you just need to check if any of the two contain duplicates.

We could simply compare the total count of the lists with the count of the list when we remove all possible duplicates:

```
var duplicateServices = countedSchedules != data?.Schedules?.Distinct().Count();
var duplicateUsers = multipleJMBGs.Count() != multipleJMBGs.Distinct().Count();
```

**UPDATE #2:**
Sounds like you want to join the two lists together and not necessarily convert it to a dictionary, what we want to do instead is create a new List so we can group that on the combination of the two properties.

```
var containsDuplicates = multipleJMBGs.Zip(serviceIds, (JMBG, serviceId) => new { JMBG, serviceId })
                                             .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.JMBG) && x.serviceId > 0) // Filter AFTER zipping the two lists together
                                             .GroupBy(x => x).Any(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

Do be aware that you are removing elements in both lists, meaning that the order might not be correct. You could instead add a `Where` clause after you zip the lists like in the example above.

Comment: this works, but I need to check if these Users are the same? So I assume that I can group by value and the key?

Comment: I think it's already safe to assume that your users are unique, with how they are split up into their own variables. Otherwise you could do a `GroupBy` on `x.Key` instead of `x.Value`, in order to check the users for duplicates.

Comment: yes, but I need both to match up. I need to have count > 0 where same users have same services.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you mean to check whether a completely identical row exists in your dictionary: something like `{ "user1", "service1" }, {"user1", "service1"}` correct? A dictionary does not allow for duplicate keys, so it should throw an exception if you call `userServicer.Add` with a key that already exists in the Dictionary.

Comment: Exactly! Please check my updated question (update #1). I think I can just do two groupBy and then just ask if count of those are bugger than 1, that means that there are users with same id and same service.

Comment: I have updated my answer for this situation.

Comment: I saw it, but it doesnt help. Basically it returns false when services are different, and users are the same. Basically What I need is to compare services and users. here is the image of one of possible states: https://i.imgur.com/08Q8Ehw.png So I need to match cross-lists, and to find if there same services for same users.

Comment: Alright, now it's clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. I have updated my answer once more. There might be inaccuracies as I typed this on my phone, fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0):

You can group the services by Id to get information on duplicates:

```cs
var groups = data?.Schedules
    .Select((service, index) => (service, index))
    .GroupBy(x => x.service.Id);
foreach (var g in groups) {
    if (g.Count() == 1) {
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Service Id {g.Key} exists once for user index {g.First().index}");
    } else {
        string indexes = String.Join(", ", g.Select(t => t.index.ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine(
            $"Service Id {g.Key} is shared by user indexes {indexes}");
    }
}
```

If you don't call `multipleJMBGs.RemoveAll(...)`, then the indexes in the users list will match the indexes of the services. So you can easily get the JMBG assigned to a service.

```cs
var groups = data?.Schedules
    .Select((service, index) => (service, index))
    .GroupBy(x => x.service.Id);
foreach (var g in groups) {
    if (g.Count() == 1) { // Service is unique
        var service = g.First().service;
        int index = g.First().index;
        string user = multipleJMBGs[index];
        ...
    } else { // Services assigned to more than one user.
        var serviceId = g.Key;
        var service = g.First().service;
        foreach (var t in g) {
            int index = t.index;
            string user = multipleJMBGs[index];
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```